# Spring: Suitable MessageConverter for Long, Integer types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

According to this post here  (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest), there are no default Spring HttpMessageConverters for Long's and Integers.

> By default, the following HttpMessageConverters instances are
>   pre-enabled:
>
> **ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter** – converts byte arrays
>   **StringHttpMessageConverter** – converts Strings
>   **ResourceHttpMessageConverter** – converts
>   org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
>   **SourceHttpMessageConverter** – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
>   **FormHttpMessageConverter** – converts form data to/from a
>   **MultiValueMap. Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter** –
>   converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on
>   the classpath) 
>   **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** – converts JSON
>   (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
>   **MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter** – converts JSON (added only if
>   Jackson is present on the classpath) **AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter** –
>   converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
>   **RssChannelHttpMessageConverter** – converts RSS feeds (added only if
>   Rome is present on the classpath)

I'm currently converting my Long into a String through the `String.valueOf()` method and then sending it over as a string.

Is there any better way to do this besides writing your own custom HttpMessageConverter?

These are for scenarios where you just want to update a certain value on your frontend, you don't need to download the whole object again, just that value.

Comment: So your handler returns a value like `123` and you want that to be the entire body of the response? What content type?

Comment: Yes. The whole content would be the value 123. I don't need anything else. Let say you just want to update a certain value on your frontend, you don't need to download the whole object again, just that value.